# why bootstrap class d-sm-none still displays image in small screen

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I desire a row with 2 columns by using bootstrap4:
1st column takes size 9 in all viewports
2nd column takes size 3 in `lg` and `md` but disappears in sm viewport.

I tried the following with `d-none`/`d-sm-none` but it does not work as expected

```
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9">
              <h1>Col-1: MD-9 or LG-9</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 d-sm-none">
            <h1>Col-2: MD-3, LG-3, SM NONE</h1>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

`d-none` disappears 2nd column regardless the viewport size
`d-sm-none` disappears 2nd column at `lg` and `md` but appear in `sm`..

here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/chris-lam/pen/zYxBBgg)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I found the answer.

`d-*-none`/`d-none` is for hiding the element in the column, not the columns itself.. so the answer is

```
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9">
              <h1>Col-1: MD-9 or LG-9</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
            <h1 class="d-sm-none d-md-block">Col-2: MD-3, LG-3, SM NONE</h1>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks.